TwinCAT generate license errors upon activation for unused licenses
My TwinCAT project shows below license errors when the code is activated.

The activate still goes through, and I can still log-in to online code.
But what is odd to me is: the error list shows TwinCAT is looking for OPCUA Server license and Modbus server license, whereas the project is not using those.
I'm only using the basic PLC license and below are screenshots from the license tab. And automatic detection of project license is not turned off.


Although it doesn't seem to cause any trouble. I would appreciate it if anyone can explain this.

is this a new project on an older PLC that was used for something else? If so ive seen this before and had to delete my _boot and _config folder etc

To me it seems like the PLC project is incorrect?

@chrisbeardy yes it is tested on an older PLC, which was used for something else which I'm not sure of. I will give that a try and see how it goes. Thanks

@ziga the PLC is an old project which has been deployed before. And as stated, it does run fine. But for sure something awkward is happening here

You got a few things that don't look normal. Look close at the errors. Missing a license dongle or something?
#2. Connection to license dongle interrupted
#4. Core dump from 2023?
#6. AdsWarning 0x7 target machine not found.
